# how to save the generated QR-code using react-native-qrcode

Tags: react-native

I am trying to generate QR code, by using this module ['react-native-qrcode'](https://github.com/cssivision/react-native-qrcode), Here I got generated QR code like this, How can I save this QR code.
[image]

Can anyone give me suggestions that how to save this generated qr,any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The library you use [uses a webview](https://github.com/cssivision/react-native-qrcode/blob/master/lib/Canvas.js#L21), therefore you have no image you may save. To save the QR code in a conceptional fashion you may store the value provided and put it into the component as you would like to display it. If you need to get the image, you would need to extend the [webview javascript part](https://github.com/cssivision/react-native-qrcode/blob/master/lib/Canvas.js#L24) to use [the ImageData interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) of the canvas. This is IMHO quite tricky and I am not entirely sure if it is even possible to get data back from the web view.

Answer (score 0):

Use [rn-qr-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-qr-generator) to generate a QR code. It will return a path or base64 of generated Image.  Later you can use [CameraRoll](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll) module to store the image in CameraRoll (or Gallery on android).

```
import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';
import CameraRoll from "@react-native-community/cameraroll";
 
RNQRGenerator.generate({
  value: 'your_qr_string_value_here',
  height: 100,              // height of the output image
  width: 100,               // width of the output image
  base64: false,            // default 'false'
  backgroundColor: 'black', // default 'white'
  color: 'white',           // default 'black'
})
  .then(response => {
    const { uri, width, height, base64 } = response;
    this.setState({ imageUri: uri });
    CameraRoll.save(uri);
    
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('Cannot create QR code', error));
```

Before calling `CameraRoll.save` make sure you have permission to save the image. Permission example see [here](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll#permissions).